# gdb "run" with error "...Cannot execute: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb

I am Ubuntu 10.04 user and I wrote a very simple program, which I compiled with `gcc`:

```
xyz@xyz-desktop:~/xyz/projects/C\C++/epollsvr/src$ gcc -g -o test test.c
```

Then I loaded it with gdb:

```
xyz@xyz-desktop:~/xyz/projects/C\C++/epollsvr/src$ gdb test
```

Then I ran it:

```
(gdb) run

Starting program: /home/xyz/xyz/projects/C\C++/epollsvr/src/num*
/bin/bash: /home/xyz/xyz/projects/CC++/epollsvr/src/num: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: /home/xyz/xyz/projects/CC++/epollsvr/src/num: cannot execute: No 
such file or directory

During startup program exited with code 126.
(gdb)
```

Could anybody tell me why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're running the correct program… The first line from `gdb` *should* be `Starting program: …/test`… Are you sure you're running exactly the commands you've shown here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try checking your path:

```
Starting program: /home/xyz/xyz/projects/C\C++/epollsvr/src/num*
```

it has `C\C++` in it whereas gdb says:

```
/bin/bash: /home/xyz/xyz/projects/CC++/epollsvr/src/num: No such file or directory
```

`C\C++` is made into `CC++`. I would guess that's why it can't find the file.

Comment: My point is try running it from a different location which wouldn't have `C\C++` in the path.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm now.
So, this thread is closed.